# How to code a foreign key in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi this is the table I am trying to create:

```
CREATE TABLE images

(

id PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL INT,

product_id FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL INT,

src varchar(255) NOT NULL

)
```

But its not letting me (I am getting a syntax error).  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IMAGES(
Id int NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_ID int NOT NULL,
src varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(P_Id)
 )
```

and make sure you build the Products table first , and do the reference foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Check out [InnoDB Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for the right syntax to use. In particular, you need to declare the column you're referencing when you create a foreign key.

Additionally, since you're using MySQL, make sure your tables use `InnoDB`, otherwise the foreign keys won't actually get enforced.